# Terraform not accepting AWS credentials from vars/tfvars files

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

In my `terraform` directory I have several `.tf` files among which:

`vars.tf`

```
variable "AWS_ACCESS_KEY" {}    
variable "AWS_SECRET_KEY" {}
```

and `terraform.tfvars`

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY="xxxxxxxxx"
AWS_SECRET_KEY="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

however,

```
$ terraform init

Initializing the backend...

Error configuring the backend "s3": No valid credential sources found for AWS Provider.
  Please see https://terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html for more information on
  providing credentials for the AWS Provider

Please update the configuration in your Terraform files to fix this error
then run this command again.
```

Do I need to set them as env vars too?

Comment: What does your `terraform` block look like? Specifically the `backend` block inside it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the AWS provider picks up your environment variables automatically when you define the provider as `provider "aws" {}`, it doesn't apply the same magic to looking up `tfvars`.

In order to use the variables from `vars.tf` you'll need to add those to your provider definition[[1]](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html):

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "${var.access_key}"
  secret_key = "${var.secret_key}"
}
```

You can also use a [shared credentials file](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html#shared-credentials-file) if you'd prefer.